# How can I access the parent controller when rendering polymorphic models?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am using a polymorphic model called 'todos' where many other models can have todos. I am needing a way to access whatever current resource I am on from the Todos controller (because it can change). Whatever the 'todoable' is. So if I am on the 'clinic' page I need to know what that model is in the todos controller. Is there a way to do something like:

```
needs: ['parent']
todoable: -> @get 'parent.content'
```

or:

```
todoable: Em.computed 'parentController', -> @get 'parentController.content'
```

or:

```
todoable: Em.computed 'parentModel', -> @get 'parentModel'
```

and get the controller/model for the active route? Thank you in advance for the help. Here is some of my code:

Rendering 'todos' from a 'patient':

```
<h1>{{fullName}}</h1>
Email: {{email}} <br />
{{render 'todos/module' todos}}
```

Todos controller:

```
App.TodosModuleController = Ember.ArrayController.extend
```

Todos model:

```
App.Todo = DS.Model.extend

  todoableId: DS.attr 'number'
  todoableType: DS.attr 'string'
  content: DS.attr 'string'
  dueDate: DS.attr 'date'
  dueEvent: DS.attr 'string'
  completedOn: DS.attr 'date'
  creatorId: DS.attr 'number'
  assigneeId: DS.attr 'number'
  markedCompleteById: DS.attr 'number'
  createdAt: DS.attr 'date'
```

Patient model:

```
App.Patient = DS.Model.extend
  firstName: DS.attr 'string'
  lastName: DS.attr 'string'
  todos: DS.hasMany 'todo', async: true
```

Todos partial:

```
<h2>Todos</h2>
<form {{action 'createTodo' on='submit'}}>
  {{input type='text' value=newTodoContent placeholder='Add a new todo'}}
  <button type='submit'>Save</button>
</form>

{{#each}}
  {{content}} - Due {{fromNow dueDate}} on {{dateFormatted dueDate}}<br />
{{/each}}
```

Comment: Why do the todo's need to know the parent resource? Just curious. There are a number of ways to find the current route. Easiest one is `currentPath` with is available in the application controller. Could you also maybe show what the todos partial looks like?

Comment: I think the main problem is that I don't know the correct way to do polymorphic associations with Ember and Rails. After reading 100 different resources this is just the best I've come up with but I know it's probably not the best way. I'll add the partial. Thanks for the help.

Comment: For sure, no worries. Ember and Ember-data can be pretty arcane, unfortunately. I was just wondering what would be truly polymorphic about your todo items, and I think it'll be obvious as to what you are trying to do if we can see your template. :)

Comment: Seriously. I've been struggling with poly's in Ember for days. So right now a todo can belong to a patient, clinic, or organization. I need to know whatever the current resource is so that I can get the todoableId and todoableType for whatever page I'm on.

Comment: Okay I am refactoring your models to make them poly. Gimme a few minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so if you really want this to be polymorphic, you need to treat `Todos` as the base abstraction.

1. A user can have many todos.
2. A todo can only belong to one user.
3. A todo can be polymorphic, so we will expect the children to extend from that class.

So, your models should looks something like this:

```
App.User = DS.Model.extend
  //...
  todos: DS.hasMany 'todo', polymorphic: true
  //...
```

Not sure if that coffeescript is valid syntax. Has been a while since I've written any.

So you now have some user that has a lot of todos, and those todos can be different enough to require polymorphism. Let's start by creating your todo that all todo types will extend from.

```
App.Todo = DS.Model.extend
  user: DS.belongsTo 'user' // May as well keep this association alive for ease of use?
  type: DS.attr 'string' // you can find this via currentPath when creating records
  content: DS.attr 'string'
  dueDate: DS.attr 'date'
  dueEvent: DS.attr 'string'
  completedOn: DS.attr 'date'
  creatorId: DS.attr 'number'
  assigneeId: DS.attr 'number'
  markedCompleteById: DS.attr 'number'
  createdAt: DS.attr 'date'
```

Okay so now you have a base todo model with all the shared stuff that the children need. Now, we `extend` from `Todo`! That is the secret sauce. Now you can add or override any of those properties on a per-model basis.

```
App.PhoneCall = App.Todo.extend //Notice that we are extending the parent
   specialPhoneCallProperty: DS.attr()

App.DoctorsNote = App.Todo.extend
   specialDoctorProperty: DS.attr()
```

If you need to set the current type during creation, try adding the `ApplicationController` as a `need` and use the array produced by `this.get('controllers.application.currentPath').split('.')`

**All that said, I'm not sure if you've actually demonstrated the need for polymorphism. I don't really see different todo types. Only different todo "owner" types.**

Now for example, if you wanted to create `Appointment`s that were polymorphic, that makes sense to me. `Physical`, `Checkup`, `WartRemoval`, `RabiesVaccination`, etc. are all sensible extensions that can have unique attributes.

Todos are just... todos.

Hope that helps!

UPDATE::

Okay so what sounds like you need is a `has_many :through` and a bridge table for each object that can own a todo. `Clinic` has many `Todo` through `ClinicTodo`. `Todo` belongs to `Clinic` through `ClinicTodo`. Do the same for `PatientTodo` and `OrganizationTodo`.

That allows each object to own many todos. Do it on both the rails and ember side.

Comment: Thanks a ton for all the work. I actually tried that model solution like 10 times but I might have missed something. I will try it again. On the polymorphic need, maybe I misunderstand the use of polymorphic but if I have a 'todo' and it can belong to a 'patient', 'clinic', or 'organization', how can I distinguish between them unless I have a poly relationship like: ('todoableId: 1, todoableType: 'Patient')? I'm coming from the rails world so my thinking is geared that way.

Comment: Also, one other problem that I could see with that model solution was that if (and I do) I have more than one poly model that let's say 'user' needs to inherit from, how can I accomplish that? Like if a user had a poly relationship with todos and appointments, how do you inherit from both? Do you have a class that inherits from both and then the user inherits from that class?

Comment: Those are really good questions. So now you should ask yourself, how do the todos change based on their ownership? Is a patient todo different from a clinic todo? If so, how, and can you describe that thing using a noun? You may just need a bridge table/model, and not a polymorphic relationship. Again, to me, your todos just look like todos.

Comment: Thanks again. In answer to that, the only way that they differ is by what object they belong to. They can belong to many different objects of different types. That is what is confusing me. If this wasn't poly I don't know how I would only show todos for 'clinic 1' on the 'clinic 1' page or for 'patient 5' or whatever. Like you said I could do a belongsTo to hasMany table in between but that seems like it would not be very DRY. There would have to be a linking table for each different model to the todos.

Comment: Thanks again Matthew. I will try what you have suggested.

Comment: It may not seem DRY, but you really aren't repeating yourself. Each of those declarations is different and unique. Using polymorphism here would be like hammering a nail with a knife.